# How to group custom dimension values by range

Tags: google-analytics

Using Universal Analytics, I have a custom dimension set up to track a user's salary. Examples of values for the dimension are: 48543.90, 121576.87.

I want to be able to use ranges in my custom report based on the salary dimension but can not figure out how to do this. For instance, I would like to see data by salary ranges:

- $0 to $39,999
- $40,000 to $79,999
- $80,000 to $119,999
- $120,000 and above

I guess I could always send the range as my value instead of the amount. For instance, send  '$40,000 to $79,999' instead of the 48543.90, but that does not give me the flexibility to change my range values later or use different ranges for different reports.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if your account has access to [Content Grouping](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167)? I believe Google is rolling this out slowly, so I'm not sure if all account have it, but I think you might be able to group event values (don't quote me on that). I can't think of a way inside GA of being able to group values, other than what you've suggested, or export to excel and do your analysis there.

UPDATED: Here is a thought, you could create an advanced segment for each range you'd like to look at:

[image]

Comment: I've had a look at an account that has content grouping enabled, and I don't think it would work with custom dimensions - the only dimensions offered are url (page) page name or screen name respectively.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I wasn't sure without looking at it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I think the purpose of content grouping is to related similar page-types, especially for flow reports...

Answer (score 0):

**Numeric range grouping** is hard to do in (standard) Google Analytics. What I have always suggested was to actually send **two** CustomVars -- exact value AND group range.

Might be tricky if you are out of customvar slots, in which case I would extract the raw data via API and do the magic in Excel (as Blexy already suggested) or any other reporting tool like Tableau that allows creating "bins" with specified numeric range.

**Another way would be to switch to Universal Analytics and use custom dimensions.**

You could then set up a set of filters that would replace the actual value (sent via custom dimension) with value ranges, using regular expression like:

```
^[1-5]?[0-9]{1,3}$
```

This would give you any number below 60,000. Similar rules could be created to take care of all ranges required... And if you send the same value with CustomMetric, you will keep the original value as well!